# Mensagem de retorno do phpMailer não é recebida

Tags: php, ajax

Estou enviando um formulário via AJAX gravando os campos do mesmo no meu banco, espero uma resposta após o envio das informações via e-mail pelo phpMailer, mas essa mensagem não ocorre.

O *script* é disparado, faço a gravação no banco, envio o e-mail mas a mensagem de confirmação não ocorre.

Faço isso:

```
        $InsComentario = "INSERT INTO contato ( nome, email, uf, municipio, telefone, grupo, assunto, mensagem, status ) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$email."', '".$uf."', '".$municipio."', '".$telefone."', '".$grupo."', '".$assunto."', '".$mensagem."', 1)";
    $sucesso = mysql_query($InsComentario) or die(mysql_error());   

    if ($sucesso > 0){

        // Envio dos e-mails
        include('processoContato.php');             
        $arr['tipo'] = "1";
        $arr['msg']  = utf8_encode('<p style="color:#669900">O contato foi registrado com sucesso</p>');            


    } else {
        $arr['tipo'] = "0";
        $arr['msg']  = utf8_encode('<p style="color:#f25824">Erro ao inserir registro no banco</p>');
    }
```

E o phpMailer está assim:

```
<?php

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// ---------------------------------------------
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = ""; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->Username = ''; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = ''; // Senha do servidor SMTP

// Define o remetente
// ------------------
$mail->From = 'emailsdosite@moveissaobento.com.br'; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Moveis Sao Bento"; // Seu nome

// Define os destinatário(s)
// -------------------------
$mail->AddAddress($email,$nome); // Cliente
$mail->AddAddress($emailMaster, $nomeLoja); // Administrador da Loja
$mail->AddCC($emailSecundario, 'Ciclano'); // Cópia para Responsável

// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
// ------------------------------------
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// Data e Hora
// data e hora do orçamento
$data = date("Y-m-d");
$hora = date("H:i:s");  
$mostradata=substr($data,8,2).'/'.substr($data,5,2).'/'.substr($data,0,4); 

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
// -----------------------------------
$mail->Subject  = "Contato via site"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "<div align=left>
  <style type='text/css'>
    <!--
    .style1 {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    -->
    </style>
      <table width=600 border=0>
        <tr>
          <td width='18%' align='left'>
            <div align='left'></div>
          <div align='left'></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align='left'><p align='left' class='titulos'>Data do Contato - $mostradata - Hora - $hora<br>
                               Assunto - $assunto <br>
                               Nome - $nome <br>
                               E-mail - $email <br />                                  
                               Cidade - $nomeCidade - UF - $nomeUF  <br>
                               Telefone - $telefone <br>
                               Comentário - $mensagem <br>
                               </p>
                               <p align='center' class='titulos'>
                                    Esse e-mail foi enviado automaticamete, não responda.
                               </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>";


// Envia o e-mail
// ---------------
$mail->Send();

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
// ----------------------------------
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

?>

[Acesse o Formulário](http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/contato)

Comment: cade as configurações de host, port, pass, user ?

Comment: Retirei os valores para enviar para o forum.

Comment: Verificou se o `send()` retorna true? nessa 'reposta' após a leitura do email seria enviado para você um email confirmando?

Comment: Olá @rray, não, não peço a confirmação e o send() retorna true sim.

Comment: @adventistapr Adicione `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1` ou descomente essa linha e troque o 2 por 1. O PHPMailer vai imprimir as mensagens de debug e possíveis erros na hora do envio. Adicione as mensagens geradas à sua pergunta (antes verifique se não existe nenhuma informação privada).

Comment: verifique se o seu php esta com o `openssl` habilitado e use a porta 587